# How to solve "different pages get the same result" when writing crawler？

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

I use spider to crawl "https://nj.zu.ke.com/zufang" .I found that the URL composition is roughly: https://{0}.zu.ke.com/zufang/pg{1}.

And each listing has a unique listing number, which constitutes a link to a specific page for access.
So I set up two MySQL columns: 1. Auto-increment ID as the primary key, 2. Listing number is unique and not null.

However, during the crawling process, by changing the number of pages of "pg{1}", the repetition ratio of the listing number obtained is extremely large, 30 items per page, roughly 100 pages, and the final result is only more than 300 items.(at first, I think I didn’t write code right.Later, I checked the number of loops with a single thread to see if there were any problems with the return. I found that many IDs returned on different pages were duplicated with print)

Later, I thought it was a problem with the recommendation system. Then I logged in and wrote the cookie. The result was roughly the same.

And if you refresh directly after visiting the page, the result will be different .

How to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: What is your question?  Do you want to get rid of the duplicates once you've scraped them, or are you asking how you can prevent getting duplicates from the website in the first place?

Comment: I don’t need to delete duplicates, I have a unique and not null listing numbe (the website is used to mark items). I want to know how to get more different items. Because the website shows 52270 items, I can only crawl about 300 items at a time.@Pranav Hosangadi

Comment: Repeated crawling multiple times will increase this number. But roughly repeated crawling of 100 pages at a time can add 100. I want to avoid having the same results appear on different web pages so that I can crawl more data. @Pranav Hosangadi